# Strange thing on regex or operator

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple compiler. In one of the keyword regex I found unexpected thing.

```
/class|method|function|constructor|int|boolean|char|void|var|static|field|let|do|if|else|while|return|true|false|null|this/.test("print") // returns true
```

I also tried in online regex tools and shows a match.

Comment: Yeah, and? The string "print" contains "int".

Comment: Maybe add word boundaries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it matches `int` from `print`, you need to have word boundaries

```js
console.log(/\b(?:class|method|function|constructor|int|boolean|char|void|var|static|field|let|do|if|else|while|return|true|false|null|this)\b/.test("print"))
```